# Изменение имени пакета и release-ключа у опубликованного приложения, стоит ли?

Tags: android, google-play

Заказывали разработку мобильного приложение у студии, студия закончила разработку и релизнула его в Play Market подписав своим ключом, а самое главное - с именем пакета, содержащим не название приложения, а название студии. (недочет при формировании ТЗ). Я сейчас отвечаю за поддержку этого приложения и передо мной встали вопросы:

Стоит ли изменять имя пакета и переподписывать своим ключом, и выкладывать это все, как новое приложение, а старое удалять? (только ради имени пакета с фирменным названием)

Можно ли изменить имя пакета и выложить, как обновление?

Если все же стоит и это сделать можно, то как лучше поступить (поступили бы Вы), чтобы перегнать пользователей из старой версии в новую? (Думал пушем уведомить)

Comment: на ваш вопрос нет объективно правильного ответа. Стоит ли - решать именно вам. С другим пакетом или ключем залить обновление невозможно.

Comment: @metalurgus хорошо, спасибо за совет, а как бы Вы поступили с перегоном пользователей из старого в новое приложение ?

Comment: выпустил бы обновление, которое бы ничего не делало, кроме как показывало диалог о том, что это приложение больше не работает, вот тут лежит новая версия.

Comment: @metalurgus да, в принципе, как я и думал, ещё раз спасибо за Ваше мнение!